# Flash Player not working on latest Chrome under Xenial

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I've looked through the various questions & answers on this topic. However, I thought that I'd post a new question as Xenial is LTS & I have the latest version 65.0.3325.162-1 of Chrome installed from the official website [here](http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/).

On [BBC website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-43408961), I see an 'area' (where I should be able to play a video by Prof Murray Shanahan) saying:

```
You need flash to play this. Enable it in your browser or download Flash Player here.
```

BTW it's a pain to type what's in 'areas' like the above. It would be nice if I could attach a screenshot.

I have subsequently installed the adobe-flashplugin package without success. I've noticed on the other questions regarding flash, that it's not recommended to use PepperFlash or FreshPlayer. Given that recent version of Chrome are supposed to have flash player builtin, what's going on and how can I play flash on the above BBC webpage.

Comment: Please note that `adobe-flashplugin` or other plugin packages don't apply to Google Chrome, which has Flash Player built-in. If you have a problem with Flash Player on Google Chrome, it's a pure Google Chrome issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable Flash for this website by allowing it to run :

[image: alt]

Reload page after this change and You should be able to play Flash videos.